# 'NoneType' Object is not callable. Python

Tags: python, object, raspberry-pi, gpio

I tried to code a little game for a raspberry pi in Python (Like the game "Not-Not"). But i always get the error: `'Nonetype' Object is not callable`, which actually makes no sense? After the Welcome screen the game actually should start with a countdown and then a random color should be able to see on the Display. If you press the right button it should give you a higher score and continue until it reaches a score of 1000. If you hit the wrong button, you will get minus 100 score. If the score reaches 0 the game should end.

Also im new to python. Thanks for your answers :).

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 316, in <module>
    Menu()
  File "game.py", line 114, in Menu
    Start_Game()
  File "game.py", line 139, in Start_Game
    Random_Sequency()
  File "game.py", line 118, in Random_Sequency
    random.choice(Sequenzen)()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

This is the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import lcddriver 
import random

lcd = lcddriver.lcd()

lcd.lcd_clear()

#Welcome

lcd.lcd_display_string("   Welcome to", 1)
lcd.lcd_display_string("   Not-Not :)", 2) 

#End Welcome 

InputPin = 35 #Rot
InputPin2 = 32 #Blau
InputPin3 = 37 #Gruen
InputPin4 = 38 #Gelb 

OutputPin = 11 #Rot
OutputPin2 = 12 #Blau
OutputPin3 = 13 #Gruen
OutputPin4 = 15 #Gelb 

BuzzerPin = 40 #Buzzer 

WaitTime = 0.5 #Wartezeit 

#SETUP

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(InputPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #Input 1

GPIO.setup(InputPin2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #Input 2
GPIO.setup(InputPin3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #Input 3
GPIO.setup(InputPin4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #Input 4

GPIO.setup(OutputPin, GPIO.OUT) #Output 1

GPIO.setup(OutputPin2, GPIO.OUT) #Ouput 2
GPIO.setup(OutputPin3, GPIO.OUT) #Output 3
GPIO.setup(OutputPin4, GPIO.OUT) #Output 4 

#SETUP ENDE

#ENGINE

SCORE = 0

#Hauptmenue

def Menu(): 
    #Hauptmenue hier hin.
    Start_Game()
    #Hauptmenue Ende 

def Random_Sequency():
    random.choice(Sequenzen)()

#Spiel
def Start_Game():
    global SCORE

    lcd.lcd_clear()

    while(SCORE >= 0): 
        while(SCORE < 1000):

            lcd.lcd_display_string("Game starts in:", 1)
            lcd.lcd_display_string("3 Seconds.", 2)
            time.sleep(1)
            lcd.lcd_display_string("2 Seconds..", 2)
            time.sleep(1)
            lcd.lcd_display_string("1 Second...", 2)
            time.sleep(1)

            lcd.lcd_display_string("PRESS:", 1)

            Random_Sequency()

        lcd.lcd_display_string("Congratulations:", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("YOU WON!", 2)
        time.sleep(5)
        SCORE = 0

        Menu() 



    lcd.lcd_display_string("    GAME", 1)
    lcd.lcd_display_string(" OVER :(", 2)
    time.sleep(5)
    SCORE = 0

    Menu()

#SEQUENZEN

#Blau
def Blue():
    global SCORE
    lcd.lcd_display_string("BLUE", 2)
    if(GPIO.input(InputPin2) == 1):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :)", 2)
        print("Knopf BLAU gedrueckt!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 0)
        print("Richtig!")
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE + 50
        Random_Sequency()
    elif((GPIO.input(InputPin) == 1) or (GPIO.input(InputPin3) == 1) or (GPIO.input(InputPin4) == 1)):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :(", 2)
        print("Falsch!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 0)
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE - 100
        Random_Sequency()
#Blau Ende

#Rot
def Red():
    global SCORE
    lcd.lcd_display_string("RED", 2)
    if(GPIO.input(InputPin) == 1):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :)", 2)
        print("Knopf ROT gedrueckt!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 0)
        print("Richtig!")
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE + 50
        Random_Sequency()
    elif((GPIO.input(InputPin2) == 1) or (GPIO.input(InputPin3) == 1) or (GPIO.input(InputPin4) == 1)):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :(", 2)
        print("Falsch!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 0)
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE - 100
        Random_Sequency()
#Rot Ende

#Gruen
def Green():
    global SCORE
    lcd.lcd_display_string("GREEN", 2)
    if(GPIO.input(InputPin3) == 1):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :)", 2)
        print("Knopf GRUEN gedrueckt!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 0)
        print("Richtig!")
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE + 50
        Random_Sequency()
    elif((GPIO.input(InputPin) == 1) or (GPIO.input(InputPin2) == 1) or (GPIO.input(InputPin4) == 1)):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :(", 2)
        print("Falsch!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 0)
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE - 100
        Random_Sequency()
#Gruen Ende

#Gelb
def Yellow():
    global SCORE
    lcd.lcd_display_string("YELLOW", 2)
    if(GPIO.input(InputPin4) == 1):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :)", 2)
        print("Knopf GELB gedrueckt!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 0)
        print("Richtig!")
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin4, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE + 50
        Random_Sequency()
    elif(GPIO.input(InputPin) == 1 or GPIO.input(InputPin3) == 1 or GPIO.input(InputPin2) == 1):
        lcd.lcd_display_string("<><><><><><><><>", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("      :(", 2)
        print("Falsch!")
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 0)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 0)
        time.sleep(WaitTime)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin2, 1)
        GPIO.output(OutputPin3, 1)
        SCORE = SCORE - 100
        Random_Sequency()

Sequenzen = [Blue(), Red(), Green(), Yellow()]

#Inititation des Spieles 
try:
    while True:
        Menu()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup() 
#Initiation des Spieles Ende

#ENGINE ENDE
```

Comment: What do you have in `Sequenzen` ? If `[None]` then you get `None()` in line `random.choice(Sequenzen)()`

Comment: `Sequenzen = [Blue(), Red(), Green(), Yellow()]` your list contains a bunch of `None`'s, because all those functions that you call to create them return `None`. Try `print(Sequenzen)`. It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do, but that is your problem

Comment: You've posted way to much code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: ```Sequenzen``` should contain a few functions which should be randomly called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that when you do this:

```
Sequenzen = [Blue(), Red(), Green(), Yellow()]
```

you are calling those functions then and there, so the list only contains their *results*. As has been pointed out, none of those functions return anything, so their results are all None, hence your error.

What you actually want to do is to have a list just of the functions themselves:

```
Sequenzen = [Blue, Red, Green, Yellow]
```

As an aside, the functions probably *should* return something: namely the updated score, rather than using a global variable.

And also note, those functions are all very similar and could probably be reduced to a single function which takes a parameter to indicate which colour was pressed.

Comment: The errors dont appear anymore, but how is it possible to call a random function and repeat this process? My code always prints the countdown, 3...2...1... and then the countdown repeats. :/ Thanks.

Comment: You are calling the functions. But the logic in those functions is presumably wrong; neither of the conditions is ever true, so they immediately return and the while loop repeats. You should debug those functions in isolation - again, this would be simpler if you had a single, parameterised function.

Comment: (And finally note that you don't need to call Random_Sequency again at the end of each function; that is already being done when the while loop repeats.)

Comment: Thanks. Everything fine now :)!